# Can't load file from jar archive

Tags: java, image, swing, maven, intellij-idea

I'm beginer programmer and I tried to write classic Snake game.
I use Maven to build my project and work from IntelliJ IDEA. 
i putted my texture into folder

```
src\main\resources\com\github\poseydon42\snakegame\assets
```

It's simple png file named snake_head.png.
Then I tryied to load this image from my code, using thisa code

```
ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("/com/github/poseydon42/snakegame/assets/snake_head.png").getFile()));
```

but I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.github.poseydon42.snakegame.Game.<init>(Game.java:22)
at com.github.poseydon42.snakegame.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

How I can load this image.

P.S.: It don't work in IDE and in cmd using built jar file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instead

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/github/poseydon42/snakegame/assets/snake_head.png")));
```